# Adding new values to dictionary corrupts old save file

Tags: c#

I am using a simple method of serializing and deserializing data for my save files which looks like this

```c#
//Object that is being stored
[System.Serializable]
public class GameData{
    public int units;
    public int scanRange;
    public int gains;
    public int reputation;
    public int clicks;
    public Dictionary<string,bool> upgradesPurchased;
    public Dictionary<string,bool> upgradesOwned;
    public Dictionary<string,bool> achievementsEarned;

    public GameData(int units_Int,int scan_Range,int gains_Int,int reputation_Int,int clicks_Int,Dictionary<string,bool> upgrades_Purchased,Dictionary<string,bool> upgrades_Owned,Dictionary<string,bool> achievements_Earned){
        units = units_Int;
        scanRange = scan_Range;
        gains = gains_Int;
        reputation = reputation_Int;
        clicks = clicks_Int;
        upgradesPurchased = upgrades_Purchased;
        upgradesOwned = upgrades_Owned;
        achievementsEarned = achievements_Earned;
    }
}

//Method that handles saving the object
public void SaveFile(){
        string destination = Application.persistentDataPath + DATA_FILE;
        FileStream file;

        if (File.Exists (destination)) {
            file = File.OpenWrite (destination);
        } else {
            file = File.Create (destination);
        }

        GameData data = new GameData (GameManager.Instance.units,GameManager.Instance.scanRange,GameManager.Instance.gains,GameManager.Instance.reputation,GameManager.Instance.clicks,UpgradeManager.Instance.upgradesPurchased,UpgradeManager.Instance.upgradesOwned,AchievementManager.Instance.achievementsEarned);
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter ();
        bf.Serialize (file, data);
        file.Close ();

        NotificationsBar.Instance.ShowNotification ("Game saved success");
    }

  //Method that loads the object
  public void LoadFile(){
        string destination = Application.persistentDataPath + DATA_FILE;

        FileStream file;

        if (File.Exists (destination)) {
            file = File.OpenRead (destination);
        } else {
            UpgradeManager.Instance.FirstLoad ();
            return;
        }

        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter ();
        GameData data = (GameData)bf.Deserialize (file);
        file.Close ();

        GameManager.Instance.units = data.units;
        GameManager.Instance.scanRange = data.scanRange;
        GameManager.Instance.gains = data.gains;
        GameManager.Instance.reputation = data.reputation;
        GameManager.Instance.clicks = data.clicks;

        UpgradeManager.Instance.upgradesPurchased = data.upgradesPurchased;
        UpgradeManager.Instance.upgradesOwned = data.upgradesOwned;

        AchievementManager.Instance.achievementsEarned = data.achievementsEarned;

        Debug.Log ("Units: " + data.units);
    }
```

Theres a lot of code here but this is so everyone has a clear picture of what the entire system looks like

So the issue with this method is when adding a new value to the dictionary passed to GameData `UpgradeManager.Instance.upgradesPurchased` I will get an error when searching for data within the dictionary `key not present in dictionary`

My analysis is that due to the new value being added there is an offset in the dictionary from where the new value is placed and what used to be in that place

What I expected to happen when I first wrote out the code wa the dictionary would just autopopulate the new values and overwrite the old data

For a visual representation of what I mean lets say you have 2 upgrades

Upgrade1,Upgrade2

Now this is saved

Now the code changes and you have 3 upgrades

Upgrade1,Upgrade3,Upgrade2

What I assume would happen is the new value is just added into the save

So I am not exactly sure why this is happening....

Comment: Can't help but feel that you should be using `enum`s for your upgrade types etc not strings... Or have them all as derived types of an `abstract` upgrade class

Comment: its quite necessary for things to be set up as they are @p

Comment: That's not a particularly big issue, the main issue I've put in my answer. If all you're doing is overwriting serialised data with a new version of your class using `upgradespurchased.add("uberLASER",true)` followed by `SaveGame(file)` isn't going to corrupt anything as far as I can see

Comment: upgradesPurchased is not a static object, and it is most likely stateless. Basically everytime you instantiate a new GameData class, there is a new one. Not sure if you are loading the config then do a save, but that most likely is the case.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst I can't see the exact cause of the issue I would suggest the following:

First, take your save/load logic out of your `GameData` class and put it into a `SaveDataManager` class, that way you segregate responsibility.

From there, you can simplify your `GameData` class down to a `struct` making serialisation/desrialisation easier.

Then in your main game class whenever you have to load the game you can do something along the lines of:

```
SaveGameManger sgManager = new SaveGameManager(file);
gameData = sgManager.LoadGame()
```

This will make your code much easier to maintain and if this doesn't fix your problem it will be a lot easier to find.

Further to this, it will also allow you to build unit tests that verify the integrity of you load and save logic.

---

I've not had a chance to test it, but your separated and refactored code would look something like this (although it needs some validation checks added and whatnot):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace  temp
{

    public class GameLoop
    {
        private SaveGameManager sgManager;
        private GameData data;
        private bool isPlaying;

        public GameLoop()
        {
            sgManager = new SaveGameManager("MYSAVELOCATION");
            data = sgManager.LoadGame();
            isPlaying = true;
        }

        private void PlayGame()
        {
            while (isPlaying)
            {
                //All of your game code
            }
        }



    }

    public class SaveGameManager
    {
        private string saveFile;
        private BinaryFormatter formatter;

        public SaveGameManager(string file)
        {
            saveFile = file;
            formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        }

        public GameData LoadGame()
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(saveFile))
            {
                return (GameData)formatter.Deserialize(reader.BaseStream);
            }
        }

        public void SaveGame(GameData data)
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(saveFile))
            {
                formatter.Serialize(writer.BaseStream, data);
            }
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public struct GameData
    {
        public int units;
        public int scanRange;
        public int gains;
        public int reputation;
        public int clicks;
        public Dictionary<string, bool> upgradesPurchased;
        public Dictionary<string, bool> upgradesOwned;
        public Dictionary<string, bool> achievementsEarned;
    }



}
```

And I really would consider switching out your `string` keys for upgrades in favour of enums... Much less error prone.

Comment: im really not getting the point of seperating the logic or how to do so

Comment: The point is that a single class should do one thing and one thing only, it's the single responsibility principal. It makes things a hell of a lot easier to debug and maintain. Separating the logic is easy, just take your save/load methods and chuck them into a new class. Then you save/load from one layer up your abstraction tree

Comment: I see where your going with this sadly doesnt solve the original issue but a very nice addition